# Industrial vision camera with Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, vision, simplecv

Is there any industrial computer vision camera that comes with a Python interface, or that has a well developed third-party solution?

I have been doing some work using webcams, which are easily accessible through for example OpenCV. However, now I need a camera which is more robust and flexible. I need to be able to set certain parameters such as exposure and gain. As far as possible I want to avoid developing in other languages than Python, since Python is what I know best.

I have seen plugins such as pyueye for uEye cameras, which seems fine, except that this does not work well in Windows.

Comment: [Pymba](https://github.com/morefigs/pymba) is a Python library for interacting with Allied Vision cameras.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure why this has been voted down.  Anyway, I'm one of the core simplecv (http://simplecv.org) developers and use Industrial Cameras everyday.  We have integrated support for Allied Vision Cameras, and XIMEA cameras.

If you have the drivers installed it's literally as easy as:

```
cam = AVTCamera()
cam = Camera('ximea')
```

As for the XIMEA cameras you need to install the XIMEA camera driver that comes with the software, then build OpenCV with the flag

```
cmake -DWITH_XIMEA=ON ..
```

As for Allied Vision, you just need to install the driver and everything should work.

I've tested both USB and CURRERA model of XIMEA's camera and they work.
I've also tested on Allied Manta but should work with all their models in theory.  It's also using the allied legacy driver. At the time they have recently recently VIMBA which is their new driver, I emailed them as of last week asking when 1.1 is expected as it will include linux support but they said not for a few months. Once they do I will make sure SimpleCV is compatible.

I have not tested on windows either (linux only), but in theory should work on windows as long as drivers are installed.

Comment: It seems that Allied Vision Technologies (AVT)'s Vimba is fully supported in linux. VimbaSDK has interfaces in C, C++ and C#. There exists at least one other python wrapper that SimpleCV for the C library called Pymba (https://github.com/morefigs/pymba). It has wrapped much of the Vimba C functionality but still lack stuff like callbacks.

Comment: Yep, they eventually released for linux. We have it working in concept in the lab but haven't battle tested it.  Well aware of pymba, we've even sent pull request that have been merged (https://github.com/morefigs/pymba/pull/2).

Comment: as Xamox said : there is no particular reason to define the question as non constructive and lower the vote. The question and the answer are pertinent: they provide an accurate situation about this cameras and vision problem.

Comment: What about basler cameras? python interface for their pylon software?

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji Yes I have gotten basler cameras working as well, although it's been a long time so I don't remember the exact specifics.  Used this class: https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/blob/develop/SimpleCV/Camera.py#L3266.  Which in the comments mentions the Aravis library that it interfaced with https://github.com/sightmachine/aravis.  So your probably going to have to do some digging but I know were were able to get it working with the basler ace acA750-30gc.  That was probably 4+ years ago so your mileage may vary.

Comment: @xamox Any words on support beyond Allied Vision Cameras, and XIMEA cameras?

Comment: I'm surprised people are still finding this question useful but glad.  I don't work in the vision space anymore but I did come across scorpion vision (http://scorpionvision.com/).  It worked pretty decent, I ran into some issues using it with threading but for the most part it worked fairly well.  Also since this post has been out I believe there are a couple that have popped up (https://hackaday.io/project/5005-open-source-industrial-smart-camera).  But I do not have any personal experience with them.