# Capture video with big vertical angle from Logitech c920

Tags: opencv, camera, logitech

I want to capture a Video from the Logitech c920 with the maximal possible vertical angle using C++ and OpenCV.

The biggest possible angle i was able to achieve is pictured below. 2304x1536@2fps using the VLC Player:

[image]

As soon as i lower the resolution i loose the vertical information (1280*1240@30fps):

[image]

Switching to a 4:3 resolution (the biggest i found was 960*720@30fps), made the picture smaller at the sides instead of increasing the height:

[image]

Does anybody know how to access a Video Stream with more than 2 fps and the vertical angle from the first picture?

A list of possible resolutions i found on the [Logitech Forum](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Webcams/H264-c920-api/td-p/861862) might help someone in the future:

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 640x480 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 160x90 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 160x120 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 176x144 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 320x180 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 320x240 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 352x288 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 432x240 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 640x360 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 800x448 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 800x600 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 864x480 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 960x720 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 1024x576 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 1280x720 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 1600x896 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 1920x1080 @ 30 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 2304x1296 @ 2 fps

MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 2304x1536 @ 2 fps

Comment: This is a terrific spam!